# How to insert if result of one sub query greater than result of another subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table DMZ that contains column PR. This column can only take values 1 or 2. And i want to insert new row into DMZ where PR will be 2 if amount of rows where PR = 1 greather  than amount of rows where PR = 2 in the case if amount of (pr = 2) greather than (pr = 1) then insert 1.

How can i realize such issue?

I wrote such query but i have an error.

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Thank you in advance.

```
INSERT INTO DMZ (NDM, DDM, PR) VALUES 
((select MAX(NDM)+1 from DMZ), GETDATE(), 
(Select 
(case when 
(select Count(PR) from DMZ where PR='2') >
(select Count(PR) from DMZ where PR='1') then 1
 else 2 End)
 from DMZ))
```

Comment: Can you also add some sample data with expected result?

Answer (score 2):

You have unneeded sub-queries there, no need for `VALUES` keyword, just use `INSERT..SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO dmz (NDM, DDM, PR) 
SELECT MAX(NDM)+1, GETDATE()
, CASE WHEN 
(select Count(PR) from DMZ where PR='2') >
(select Count(PR) from DMZ where PR='1') then 1
 ELSE 2 End
FROM DMZ
```

Answer (score 1):

I find those nested subqueries to be overly complicated.  How about this?

```
INSERT INTO DMZ (NDM, DDM, PR) 
    select MAX(NDM) + 1, GETDATE(), 
           (case when sum(case when PR = 2 then 1
                               when PR = 1 then -1
                               else 0
                          end) > 0
                 then 1 else 2
            end) as PR
   from DMZ;
```

I removed the single quotes from the comparisons for PR.  It appears to be a number.  You should not compare numbers and strings.  Keep the types consistent.

In addition, the use of `max(ndm) + 1` suggests that you might really want to be using an `identity` column.